# Javascript object accessible from all browser windows?

Tags: javascript, browser, javascript-objects

is it possible to access a javascript object from all browser windows?
is there a global object to store data in?

for example: we want to put information in one window from multiple opened or later opened windows.

Thank you

Comment: Which pages would be allowed to read / edit that object's data...? If you store the data server-side using AJAX, it would be a different case which has been answered on SO before.

Comment: ajax is no solution for us because we use a javascript-based editor which can handle multiple files.
every file opened from different windows should be opened in the same editor.

Comment: All on the same domain? Which Browsers need to be supported?

Comment: you can store data in cookie. But in that case base URL must be same for all the browser windows.

Comment: yes on the same domain. Browsers: FF, IE and Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the information to the target window via window.open ,  „javascript:“  using target and even initialize  it, if it do not exists.

For example:
You have a page “mypage.html” and there a javascript object myObject, and want to pass from any window in the browser the information foo = 'hello'.

mypage.html :

```
....
var myObject = {
        qs = {},
        init:  function()
            var b = window.location.href.split("?");
            if(b.length > 1){
                var p = b[1].split("&");
                for(var i = 0; i < p.length; i++){
                    var c = p[i].split("=");
                    qs[c[0]] = c[1];
                }
            }
            this.doFoo();
        },
        doFoo: function(){
            var foo = this.qs.foo;
            ....
        }
        ...
};
myObject.init();
...
```

the calling html's:

```
window.open(
    'javascript:if(typeof(myObject) == "undefined"){'
    + 'setTimeout(\'window.location.href = "mypage.html?foo=hello"\', 10);}'
    + 'else{myObject.qs={}; myObject.qs.foo="hello"; myObject.doFoo();}'
    , "mypage"
);
```

the setTimeout is only needed for chrom, because he got the "window.location.href" property not at startup.

Answer (score 2):

As long as one window is opened from another, and they open pages in the same domain, they can access each other. If you use the `window.open` method, you get a reference to the window object of the new window, and the `window.opener` property in the new window points to the window from where it was opened.

If you open a new instance of the browser, then the windows are completely separate and there is no way for the client scripts to communicate directly. Even if you open the page in a new window in the same instance, they can't communicate because they are not aware of each other.

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting modern browsers, you can use HTML 5 storage.
http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2009/06/html5_storage_t.html

and as @Guffa said, you can have communication between parent window and child window
easily even without storage.